# Find only child nodes in TreeView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have the following tree

```
A
+-B
+-C 
| +-D
| +-E
+-F
  +-G
  +-H
```

I am trying to find `B, D, E, G, H`.
Exclude nodes that have tree and just keep their childs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the children recursively in a List of TreeNodes:

```
 List<TreeNode> children = new List<TreeNode>();

 foreach(TreeNode node in  TV.Nodes) collectChildren(node);

 void collectChildren(TreeNode node)
 {
    if (node.Nodes.Count == 0) children.Add(node) 
    else  foreach(TreeNode n in node.Nodes) collectChildren(n);
 }
```